# Python subprocess.Popen() call works in command-line but not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a very strange behavior using subprocess.Popen() in Eclipse. I'm sorry I cannot provide much useful code, because it is implemented in a commercial programm. 
But it is quite simple: in my script an executable is called via subprocess.Popen(). Calling it by hand via the command-line works. Running the Python script in command-line works as well. When using Eclipse (PyDev, Python2.7) I'm getting the following Error Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 564, in <module>
  main()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 546, in main
  known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 276, in addusersitepackages
  user_site = getusersitepackages(kind)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 244, in getusersitepackages
  user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py", line 230, in getuserbase
  from sysconfig import get_config_var
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 10, in <module>
  'stdlib': '{base}/'+sys.lib+'/python{py_version_short}',
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lib'
```

I already checked all environment variables known to me and made them equal (sys.path, os.environ). The problem still appears. What other reason can that have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you run: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.executable); import sysconfig'` via command-line and in Eclipse? Normal python has not `sys.lib`. The error can be caused by running an ordinary python executable with a patched stdlib i.e., it is wrong to use the same `sys.path` for patched (probably your OS specific python version) and a stock python (from python.org).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for your kind reply! It turned out that the problem was more or less in the PYTHONPATH-specification of the third party software I am using. This software uses it's own python installation for specific processes and things have been messed up due to the PYTHONPATH specified by PyDev. But you were right: the missing path was needed for running sysconfig. Thanks again.